# How to register/setup Azure B2C WEB Api and SPA to use Auth Code Flow?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

All the Microsoft guides, tutorials and samples that I find on B2C and Authorization Code Flow use Implicit Grant Flow or refer to another guide that uses Implicit Flow.

Here is an example of their outdated Implicit Flow guide for B2C:
[Register a web application in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-ga#enable-id-token-implicit-grant)

This guide is linked to (or an almost identical guide is used) in all the Auth Code Flow guides I have found.

Do any of you know if Microsoft has a guide, that honors the subject of the guide "auth code flow b2c" and actually shows how to setup Auth Code Flow in Azure B2C?

Maybe I am overlooking something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does, the page you've linked to there is the basic tutorial, what you actually need is the [Authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow) page which also includes some info about PKCE for SPAs and links off to sample apps showing the use of MSAL.

There's also a page about creating an [app registration for SPAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-spa) that highlights the difference between using code flow with PKCE and implicit, recommends code, and walks you through the same kinds of steps as in your linked page but targeted at SPAs.

As mentioned in that second link, *if* you want to enable the implicit flow for your app registration then under Implicit grant, select both the Access tokens and ID tokens check boxes. Because you **don't** want to enable implicit flow then  **don't** check those two boxes and your app registration will **only** support code flow. If you do check those boxes then it will support **both** implicit *and* code flow.

Comment: Thank you for feedback. The first link you post refers to a guide that uses implicit flow, when you want to see how to set it up in azure (as I wrote in my question).  The second article also shows how to do implicit grant flow - or links to articles like the first link, that refers to implict grant. Maybe the api/spa is configured to use authorization code flow if you deselect the access and id  tokens? Note: I am not asking how to write SPA's or Apis, I am asking how to configure apps and spas in B2C for Authorization Code Flow in the Azure Portal (or with Azure cli, whatever)

Comment: When you say "it refers to a guide that uses implicit flow", what do you mean? That first page is all about the authorization code flow, it does link off to other similar pages that talk about using the implicit flow, but that page itself is about how you use the code flow. The second link is about setting up the App Registration in B2C to support implicit OR code flow for a SPA. It does include a section about implicit but says that section is only IF you're using implicit. Like you say, generally it's just a case of deselecting the access and id token boxes.

Comment: Follow the guide, and find out how to register the app for authorization code flow. When you get to that section or link, notice that it describes or links to implicit grant flow.

Comment: If it is correct, that deselecting id and access token in Azure creates Auth Code Flow, then create that answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: Do you mean the "Use your own Azure AD B2C directory" section at the bottom of the first link? If so, like I mentioned before, those links are the basic tutorial for setting up something that works in almost all cases (implicit flow). The earlier "Redirect URI setup required for single-page apps" section on that page links to the second link in my answer which is specific to setting up a SPA app registration and covers both code and implicit flows. I've updated my answer to try to make it clearer which part of that second page is the important part and what it means.

Comment: Could you add this to the answer (please): *To register an app in Azure B2C to use Authorization code flow, select Authentication and under Implicit grant, make sure the Access tokens and ID tokens check boxes are un-checked.*